# What are these arrows?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, classical-guitar

I have played the guitar for 6 years now and have never seen this notation. What do these arrows mean?

[image: score]

EDIT: Bach Chaconne, arrangement by Edson Lopes, classical guitar (for electric guitar players: played with fingers, not a pick).

Comment: Just a guess so not a real answer: The advice to play both notes with a downstroke?

Comment: Need more info - composer, piece, violin or guitar, more of the page?

Comment: Your having never seen this notation before may well be because this music is not for guitar. Looks like it's for violin based on the name portion in the picture.

Comment: @Dekkadeci this is an arrangement for guitar specifically, that’s why i’m curious

Comment: @Tim https://youtu.be/9AKC6e96pno video (didn’t notice anything). Full sheet music in the description.

Comment: The first note in the next measure has two different fingerings offered.  That suggests to me that the arrows indicate that those are part of that same alternate fingering.

Comment: @Duston the first note in the next measure is a double-stop. That's not two different fingerings, it's the fret numbers for each note.

Comment: I've never seen this notation, but I would guess that the down arrow means to play the notes by hammering down on the frets, perhaps. Usually classical guitar transcriptions will indicate up or down strokes for the notes using the violin-style up and down bow markings, so I don't think it's that, although it might be given the idiosyncrasies of the notation.

Comment: @DonHosek good point.  I'm showing my piano player bias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for including more information, it is very important to see and hear things in context, like knowing the key and time signatures in order to be able to give an accurate answer.

The notes happen at about 3:56 and are at the top of page 4. The arrows indicate shifting the positioning so the 1st finger extends towards the nut and playing the F and Eb with fingers 4 and 2. This allows the quick playing of the Bb of the double stop on the downbeat with the 1st finger.